# How the parent has the key when setting up OneToMany relationship in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a table like this:

board

- id(pk)
- message_id (mapped by message)
- title_id (mapped by message)

1, 1, 2

message

- id(pk)
- lang(pk)
- content

1, en, test / 1, fr, test / 1, zh, test / 2, en, test / 2, fr, test / 2, zh, test

There are fields called message_id and table_id in board, so we want to refer to message table.

How do I create a JAP Entity to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your question right. But you'll need the ManyToOne for sure (defines the foreign key), and OneToMany if you like.

On Table entity:

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "message_id", nullable = false)
    private Message message;
```

On Message entity:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "message", targetEntity = Table.class,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Table> tables;
```

You can try to create your schema on https://bootify.io to get your Spring Data entities.